# Hibernate: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.persister.entity.DiscriminatorType.getJdbcJavaType()" because "this.discriminatorType" is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to execute a JPQL query that retrieves the 'permissions' associated to a specific 'role'. When I execute the query, this Exception is thrown:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.persister.entity.DiscriminatorType.getJdbcJavaType()" because "this.discriminatorType" is null`

This is the query:

```java
    @Query("SELECT PermissionEntity " +
            "FROM RolePermissionEntity rolePermission " +
            "JOIN PermissionEntity permission " +
            "WHERE rolePermission.role = :role")
    List<PermissionEntity> findPermissionsByRoleId(@Param("role") RoleEntity role);
```

And these are my entity models:

**RoleEntity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "roles",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "role_name_unique", columnList = "name", unique = true)
        }
)
/* Lombok annotations omitted */
public class RoleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Transient
    private List<PermissionEntity> permissions;

}
```

**PermissionEntity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "permissions",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "permission_name_unique", columnList = "name", unique = true)
        }
)
/* Lombok annotations omitted */
public class PermissionEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

**RolePermissionEntity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "role_permissions"
)
/* Lombok annotations omitted */
public class RolePermissionEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RolePermissionId id;

    @MapsId("roleId")
    @ManyToOne
    private RoleEntity role;

    @MapsId("permissionId")
    @ManyToOne
    private PermissionEntity permission;

}
```

And **RolePermissionId**

```java
@Embeddable
/* Lombok annotations omitted */
public class RolePermissionId implements Serializable {

    private Integer roleId;

    private Integer permissionId;

}
```

I'm using Spring Boot version 3.0.1 with the Spring Boot Data JPA starter with Hibernate as persistence provider.

Comment: Query doesn't look quite right: "JOIN PermissionEntity permission" did you mean to use "SELECT permission FROM RolePermissionEntity rolePermission JOIN rolePermission.permission permission WHERE  rolePermission.role = :role"? The later is using the relationship defined in RolePermissionEntity, while the first doesn't specify what to use.